# 2 WP_Query loops for custom post types on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, slider, custom-post-type

I'm having hard time with this problems since I cant figure it out.
I'm using 2 WP_Query loops for custom post types (slider and portfolio) on the same page.
I also created a custom meta box for both custom post types.

So here is the code for index.php which Im using as Home template for displaying slider and portfolio items:

```
<?php
/*

    Template Name: Home

*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="header">

            <?php rm_slider(); ?> // This is where Im calling slider function to display the slider.

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">

            <?php $loop = new WP_Query(

                array(
                    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                ));
            ?>

            <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>

            <ul class="services">

                <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <li>
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                            <?php else: ?>

                                <p>No portfolio image</p>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                        <p>Client: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_project_client', true); ?></p>
                        <p>Client website: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_project_client_url', true); ?></p>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; } ?>

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the code for slider.php:

```
<?php

// create slider markup
function rm_slider() {

    $slider_loop = new WP_Query(

        array(
            'post_type' => 'slider',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));

    if ($slider_loop->have_posts()) { ?>

        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slider-container">

                <?php while ($slider_loop->have_posts()) : $slider_loop->the_post(); ?>

                       <div>

                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                            <?php else: ?>

                                <p>No slider image</p>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="slide-info">
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php

                                $slide_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_slide_url', true);

                                if ($slide_url != '') { ?>

                                    <a href="<?php echo $slide_url; ?>" class="more-info"><?php echo $slide_url; ?></a>

                                <?php } else { echo 'empty?'; ?>

                            <?php

                                }

                            ?>

                        </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div><!-- .slider-container -->
        </div><!-- #slider -->

    <?php }

    wp_reset_query();
}

?>
```

Im sure that the actual content from custom meta boxes is there, because when I only use 1 loop, it displays perfectly. But when using both loops, it only displays custom post meta only for the portfolio section. Im struggling with this problem whole day, please help me! Thanks :)

Comment: Tough one, I'd add debug statements inside the rm_slider() function to find out at what point the function is failing if it is indeed being called.

Comment: How would I do that? Im noob in PHP :) Also the solution that @Joe provided works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, try changing this:

```
$slide_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_slide_url', true);
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_project_client', true);
```

for this:

```
$slide_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_slide_url', true);
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_project_client', true);
```

You could also try getting all post meta just to see if its all there.

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ) );
print_r($meta); // prints the meta array to the screen, check your data is there.
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe I forgot to write that I tried printing out get_post_custom and yes the data is there.


This is what I get: Array ( [_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [_edit_lock] => Array ( [0] => 1383347235:1 ) [_slide_url] => Array ( [0] => something.com ) )

Then I try what you suggested and it works. I knew there was other way to get the ID but I forgot and was trying something like $post_ID, which didnt work. But this seems to work perfectly. Could you explain to me if possible, how does this work and why $post->ID doesnt work but get_the_ID() works? 

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this. I think when you call `$loop->the_post();` It makes certain functions work like `the_title()` and `the_ID()` I have found that it also stops the $loop object from working as it would without calling `the_post();`. I think the reason that`$post->ID` does not work is because it should be `$loop->ID` and `$slider_loop->ID`

Comment: I didnt understand much because im not good in PHP but also chaning get_the_ID to $loop->ID works. Not sure if that is what you meant. So thanks again for help :)

I got one more thing not related to this, I want slider to be only available in WP admin. Because now you can go to mysite.com/slider/slide-1 and it would show the content.

Setting public -> false will fix this issue but then Slider dissapears from admin menu. I managed to show it by using, show_ui, show_in_menu, etc. but here is the problem, when creating new slide the slug box that shows URL dissapears.

Comment: The reason that `$loop->ID` works is because you called `$loop = new WP_Query();` this makes $loop into a "PHP object" to access the methods of this object you use `$loop->post_title` for example. You were calling `$post->ID` $post is not the object $loop is. For more info research "object orientated php". As for you second question i suggest you make a new question stackoverflow. Send me a massage and i will come answer it. The answer to your question is allready out there, I will give you a clue http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand a bit better now. As for the second question, it somehow fixed itself, now its working, even with public set to true, I get 404 error and I can still see it in the admin menu. Wordpress is weird sometimes :) I have other question but I will send you a PM if you could help with that. Thanks :)

Comment: I couldnt find PM option so here is the link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121194/current-menu-item-class-for-custom-post-type-parent

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, after every `WP_Query()` you should use:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

NOT <del>`wp_reset_query();`</del>. Have a try with this.

> [**`wp_reset_query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) restores the `$wp_query` and global post data to the original main query. This function should be called after `query_posts(`), if you must use that function. As noted in the examples below, it's heavily encouraged to use the `pre_get_posts` filter to alter query parameters before the query is made.

and

> [**`wp_reset_postdata()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) is used to restore the global `$post` variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using new `WP_Query`. It restores the $post variable to the current post in the main query.

And I also suggest you to try changing the possible redundant variable name like `$loop` to something like `$portfoliowLoop` etc.

Comment: I tried that already but it didnt work. Now I changed both wp_reset_query to wp_reset_postdata but still nothing.

Comment: I believe you only need to do wp_reset_query if you're using query_posts.  You should be safe if you're using new WP_Query() every time. Further reading: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts